# bootswatch-rails theme doesn't work all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootswatch

I try to use bootswatch-rails, but it doesn't work well, for example, button doesn't appear right, not like on the bootwatch site, that show.
I put bootstrap-sass and bootswatch in my gemfile and bundle install

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'bootswatch-rails', '>=0.2.0'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '>= 2.1.0.0'
```

and in my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss file looks like this

```
// First import journal variables
@import "bootswatch/cerulean/variables";

// Then bootstrap itself
@import "bootstrap";

// Responsive styles go here in case you want them
@import "bootstrap-responsive";

// And finally bootswatch style itself
@import "bootswatch/cerulean/bootswatch";
```

I really don't know what I do wrong.

Comment: Do you have bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss imported in your application.css? Or asked differently… Show us the comments in your application.css

Comment: i have different layout. in this case i use home_layout.html.erb and i create home.css.scss. this is file, the  bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss is included like @import  bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss.

Answer (score 1):

do you have any other css files being imported that you aren't taking into consideration such as scaffold.css (when you generate a resource via the scaffold command)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but as a shot in the dark I'd try putting "gem 'bootstrap-sass', '>= 2.1.0.0'" inside group :assets in your Gemfile. I'd also comment out the bootstrap-responsive styles - they sometimes get in the way.

Comment: so i should put gem 'bootstrap-sass', '>= 2.1.0.0'" inside group :assets right?